# Is a question regarding 'drawing packages with math support' acceptable?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I would like to ask if the following question is acceptable in our main site. It is directly related to LaTeX but it is not about it. I would like to ask it in our main site because I believe that LaTeX users would be the best audience for it.

"Is there a good software in which you can draw but also support math in LaTeX inside the drawing? I would like the drawings to have excellent integration in a LaTeX document in the sense that they don't stand out."

Comment: I think the question is already answered in [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents). If you want to write code for the drawings, look to the first part of the answer. If you want a separate tool for WYSIWYG-like functionality, look to the second part of the answer.

Comment: @PaulGessler I want a GUI tool that can draw without code.

Comment: then http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex is the ticket

Comment: @PaulGessler Really nice. When I searched about similar questions I didn't think to add GUI in my search. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can change your title to something more specific such as "Is a question regarding 'drawing packages with math support' acceptable?"

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok I will. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is in principle not an off-topic question, since it does relate to TeX and related tools.  However, to avoid it being closed as a duplicate, you might want to check out the following questions already on the site and only craft a new one if those answers don't answer your question:

- [What graphics packages are there for creating graphics in LaTeX documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205/2693)
- [Best option to create vector graphics with LaTeX labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78968/2693)
- [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/2693)
- [Best Drawing software for engineering/scientific illustrations with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78850/2693)

These are just a few questions already on the site that are quite similar.  Also, if you do post a new question, make sure you explain clearly what you mean by "drawing" since that is a very vague term.

Comment: Thank you. Some of the questions are really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not TikZ or PSTricks? Or are you referring to some GUI tool?

I think what you'll need to do is add more detail to what you mean by "software", "integration", etc. Otherwise, if you were to ask this question on the main site, it is likely to be closed as "already asked and answered".

Comment: I meant some GUI tool actually.